# How to disallow repeated numbers in telephone field like 1111111 or 222222

Tags: preg-match, contacts, phone-number

I am using contact form 7 and want to disallow users to enter repeated numbers like 1111111 or 2222222 in phone field.

I am using below code to enter only 10 digits. Can anyone help me with what I should change or add in this to work.

```
// define the wpcf7_is_tel callback<br> 
function custom_filter_wpcf7_is_tel( $result, $tel ) {<br> 
  $result = preg_match( '/^\(?\+?([0-9]{0})?\)?[-\. ]?(\d{10})$/', $tel );<br>
  return $result; <br>
}<br>
         
add_filter( 'wpcf7_is_tel', 'custom_filter_wpcf7_is_tel', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: How many times can a digit be repeated in a number in order to render that number invalid?

Comment: Allowed digit is 10 but don't want same number repeated more than 5 times. Also want to start 6,7,8 & 9 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `[0-9]{0}` looks like a typo as this pattern matches nothing, an empty string. You probably wanted to match an optional area code, three digits. So, use `\d{3}` if you meant that.

Next, to disallow same digits within those you match with `\d{10}`, you simply need to re-write it as `(?!(\d)\1{9})\d{10}`.

Bearing in mind what was said above, the solution is

```php
function custom_filter_wpcf7_is_tel( $result, $tel ) {<br> 
  return preg_match('/^\(?\+?(?:\d{3})?\)?[-. ]?(?!(\d)\1{9})\d{10}$/', $tel );<br>
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VaEgBn/1).

Comment: Hi, I used [0-9]{0} because I don't want more then 10 digits and its only working.  Let me check your solution.

Comment: Thank you. The solution is working for repeating digits, But I also want it to be start mobile numbers only with 9,8,7 & 6 only, pls help as I know very less about coding.

Comment: @Neeraj That is not what you asked about but you can certainly make the pattern start matching only when the first of the ten digits is `9`, `8`, `7`, or `6` if you use `[6-9]`. The pattern declaration will look like `'/^\(?\+?(?:\d{3})?\)?[-. ]?(?!(\d)\1{9})[6-9]\d{9}$/'`.